# Trying to sketch $3$ level sets of the function $f(x,y) = x^2+6xy+y^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to sketch 3 level sets of the function
$f(x,y) = x^2+6xy+y^2$. I am having trouble understanding how to draw these 2D curves if I don't know the shape in advance, i.e. $x^2+y^2$ is a circle. Can someone talk me through the process? So far i have chosen levels $z\in\{1,2,3\}$ so:
\begin{align}
x^2+6xy+y^2 &= 1, \\
x^2+6xy+y^2 &= 2, \\
x^2+6xy+y^2 &= 3.
\end{align}
How do I know what is happening in this curve?

Comment: What level are you studying?  This is a problem which in my experience is usually studied at second year university level.  If you are not up to that yet, perhaps you were supposed to use computer assistance?

Comment: By an appropriate substitution, you can rotate the axes and express the curves in terms of new variables: in this case, it turns out that the angle is $45^\circ$ so $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (X - Y)$ and $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (X + Y)$. Now, the level curves $f(x, y) = L$ become $4X^2 - 2Y^2 = L$, which are hyperbolas that cross the $X$-axis with asymptotes $Y = \pm \sqrt{2} X$. Have [a look](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ntejnd53dj).

Answer (score 1):

Since $6^2 - 4\cdot 1 \cdot 1 > 0$, these curves are hyperbolas.  You might choose one level to be $0$: this will give you two straight lines which are the asymptotes.  They divide the plane into four regions: two which contain branches of the curves for levels $> 0$ and the other two for $< 0$.

Comment: Sorry where did you get "6^2 -4*1*1>0"  from? All the info i find online uses nice functions for examples where the demonstrator just says "we already know such and such is a circle" I want to know how I go about drawing a two variable function where I don't already know what it will look like. This is for 2nd year calculus. I think I might need to the process dumbed down a little for me please.

Comment: Look up "conic sections".